# How to Highlight HTML table row with only ONE row can be highlighted?

Tags: jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("tr").removeClass();
  $("tr:gt(0)").click(function() {
    $(this).css("color", "red")
  });
});
```

```css
.highlight td {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <title></title>
  <link href="003.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>NAME</td>
      <td>AGE</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>John Smith</td>
      <td>44</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Mary Green</td>
      <td>66</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bob Black</td>
      <td>22</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

The following code is NOT working, but how to correct it?

Comment: can you please rephrase the question?

Comment: First what is your code doing? Second it looks like you are setting color to red? Shouldn't you be setting the class to highlight? Otherwise it would set to red and never clear it.

Comment: Is the issue that clicking multiple rows causes multiple rows to highlight, rather than just the last row clicked?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

maybe try changing

```
$("tr:gt(0)").click(function(){$(this).css("color","red")});
```

into

```
$("tr:gt(0)").click(function() {
        $(".highlight").removeClass("highlight");
        $(this).addClass("highlight");
    });
```

Comment: If this answers your "question" then click the checkmark and mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting any of the `<td>` to `class="highlight"` so none of the backgrounds will be red.

Comment: That is NOT the reason it doesn't work. If you run this code, the row can be highlighted, but the problem is when a new row is highlighted, the old one is still there :(

Comment: Well then you clearly did not give us all of the relevant code (or a question)